# Error in feching data from tables using joins

Tags: oracle

The `MDW_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS` table has the `CUSTOMER_ID` , `ACCOUNT_ID` and `INVOICE_ID`

The `MDW_INVOICE` table has `INVOICE_ID` , `INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID1` , `INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID2` , `INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID3`

The `MDW_INVOICE_TRANSACTION` table has `INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID`, `COST`

I am trying to print `ACCOUNT_ID`,`COST1`,`COST2`,`COST3` from the three tables using the query

```
SQL> SELECT a.account_id , to_number(i1.cost) , to_number(i2.cost) , to_number(i3.cost)
  2  FROM mdw_customer_accounts a,
  3  mdw_invoice b,
  4  mdw_invoice_transaction c
  5  LEFT JOIN mdw_invoice i1 ON b.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID1 = i1.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID
  6  LEFT JOIN mdw_invoice i2 ON b.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID2 = i2.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID
  7  LEFT JOIN mdw_invoice i3 ON b.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID3 =i3.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID
  8  WHERE a.customer_id='CUS0031' and a.invoice_id=b.invoice_id and a.STATUS='ACTIVE';
```

I am getting the following error

> LEFT JOIN mdw_invoice i1 ON b.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID1 =
>   i1.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID
>                                                          * ERROR at line 5: ORA-00904: "I1"."INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID": invalid identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT a.account_id, to_number(i1.cost), to_number(i2.cost), to_number(i3.cost)
FROM mdw_customer_accounts a
JOIN mdw_invoice b ON a.invoice_id=b.invoice_id
LEFT JOIN mdw_invoice_transaction i1 
       ON b.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID1 = i1.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID
LEFT JOIN mdw_invoice_transaction i2 
       ON b.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID2 = i2.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID
LEFT JOIN mdw_invoice_transaction i3 
       ON b.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID3 =i3.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID
WHERE a.customer_id='CUS0031' and a.STATUS='ACTIVE';
```

Comment: This gives the result for just one account id, but the mdw_customer_accounts_table can have multiple accounts per customer_id. I need to retrive all the values for that particular customer_Id

Comment: @debal: If you remove the `and a.STATUS='ACTIVE'` condition, and change the `JOIN mdw_invoice` to `LEFT JOIN mdw_invoice`, you should see all accounts for that customer (regardless of whether they are inactive or have no invoices).

Answer (score 3):

Table MDW_INVOICE does not have a column named INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID.

As you said, it has the columns INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID1, INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID2 and INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID3.

Comment: still not being able to write the query.. please help

Comment: @debal Nilo is correct, your join should not be to `mdw_invoice b` but to `mdw_customer_accounts a`

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best idea to mix notations.

```
CREATE TABLE MDW_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS(
    CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER, ACCOUNT_ID NUMBER, INVOICE_ID NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE MDW_INVOICE(
    INVOICE_ID NUMBER, INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID1 NUMBER, INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID2 NUMBER, INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID3 NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE MDW_INVOICE_TRANSACTION (
    INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID NUMBER, COST NUMBER
);

SELECT  a.account_id --, to_number(i1.cost) , to_number(i2.cost) , to_number(i3.cost) -- there is no cost column in mdw_invoice table
FROM    mdw_customer_accounts a
JOIN    mdw_invoice b       ON a.invoice_id = b.invoice_id
        -- JOIN mdw_invoice_transaction c -- join on what??? Cartesian join???
LEFT    JOIN mdw_invoice i1 ON b.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID1 = i1.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID1 -- <---- number at the end
LEFT    JOIN mdw_invoice i2 ON b.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID2 = i2.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID2 -- <---- number at the end
LEFT    JOIN mdw_invoice i3 ON b.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID3 = i3.INVOICE_TRANSACTIONID3 -- <---- number at the end
WHERE   a.customer_id='CUS0031' 
        -- AND a.STATUS='ACTIVE'; -- where is status column?
;
```

Comment: This just displays the account_id.

Comment: Sure, because it's all that is requested on the select columns' clause as above. You can put the name of the columns you want to see. It's your choice...